# How can I hide elements in my list and add a 'show more' feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I'm using javascript to build a list of results. I have a for-loop that iterates over some data and creates a mydata div, and adds that to the results div. Let's pretend it looks something like this:

```
<div id="results">
    <div class="mydata">data 1</div>
    <div class="mydata">data 2</div>
    ...
    <div class="mydata">data 20</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is **only display 5 results at a time**, and should the user wish to see more, they can click a **show next 5** or **show more** button (or something similar). Any ideas?

Just to clarify, every time the user clicks "show more" I want to 'unhide' the next 5 elements, not ALL the remaining elements. So each click reveals more elements until all are displayed.

Comment: If you are using jQuery I would suggest taking a look at this pagination plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Comment: @James Allardice, that looks like a sweet plugin. If I had a larger data set I would definitely look into using this. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `gt()` and `lt()` selectors along with `:visible` pretty well here.

The following will show the next 5 results on clicking and removes the link once all items are visible.

```
$('.mydata:gt(4)').hide().last().after(
    $('<a />').attr('href','#').text('Show more').click(function(){
        var a = this;
        $('.mydata:not(:visible):lt(5)').fadeIn(function(){
         if ($('.mydata:not(:visible)').length == 0) $(a).remove();   
        }); return false;
    })
);
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/nTv7D/

Regardless of what other people are suggesting here, I would **not** hide the elements using CSS, but do it in JS instead, because if a user has JS disabled and you hide the elements using CSS, he won't get them visible. However, if he has JS disabled, they will never get hidden, nor will that button appear etc, so it has a full noscript fallback in place + search engines don't like hidden content (but they won't know its hidden if you do it on DOM load).

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I'm looking for! Looks nice with the 'fadeIn' !

Comment: I'm not sure why, but at run time, the 'show more' anchor isn't getting created properly. I get the following error when I inspect under google chrome: "uncaught TypeError: Object#<Object> has no method 'last'"

Comment: @whoabackoff Are you getting that error on my jsfiddle or on your own implementation, as it is working fine for me in Chrome. `last()` was added in jQuery version 1.4, so if you are using an older version, then you can achieve the same result with replacing `.last()` with `.filter(":last")`

Comment: your jsfiddle worked fine. It was a jQuery version problem, all fixed now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

My solution is here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRWh9/3/).

You can put this link somewhere:

```
<a href="#" title="" id="results-show-more">show more</a>
```

and use the following code:

```
var limit = 5;
var per_page = 5;
jQuery('#results > div.mydata:gt('+(limit-1)+')').hide();
if (jQuery('#results > div.mydata').length <= limit) {
    jQuery('#results-show-more').hide();
};

jQuery('#results-show-more').bind('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    limit += per_page;
    jQuery('#results > div.mydata:lt('+(limit)+')').show();
    if (jQuery('#results > div.mydata').length <= limit) {
        jQuery(this).hide();
    }
});
```

where `limit` is your current number of results displayed and `per_page` is number of results shown with each click on "show more". The link disappears if all the results are displayed. See how it [works on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRWh9/3/).

Comment: great implementation that handles variable number of initial results and results per page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CSS class like:

```
.hiddenData { display: none }
```

and attach it to any quantity of divs that exceeds 5.

After that make handlers for adding/deleting this class from the needed quantity of divs.

jQuery for class removing:

```
$(".hiddenData").removeClass("hiddenData")
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with something like:

```
.hidden_class{
  display: none;
}
```

Add this class to all the mydata div's that you dont want seen.
when the user click the button, remove it from the next 5 div's.

repeat everytime the user clicks the "read more" button

Comment: This is very similar to Igor's answer

Answer (score 1):

This should work...Let me know how it goes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ShowHide(id) { $("#" + id).toggle(); }
</script>
<div id="results">
    <div class="mydata">data 1</div>
    <div class="mydata">data 2</div>
    <div class="mydata">data 3</div>
    <div class="mydata">data 4</div>
    <div class="mydata">data 5</div>

    <div style="clear:both" onclick="ShowHide('grp6')">More</div>
    <div id="grp6" style="display:none">
      <div class="mydata">data 6</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 7</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 8</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 9</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 10</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both" onclick="ShowHide('grp11')">More</div>
    <div id="grp11" style="display:none">
      <div class="mydata">data 11</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 12</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 13</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 14</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 15</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your forloop, you also have to add these divs hidden container

```
<div style="clear:both" onclick="ShowHide('grp6')">More</div>
    <div id="grp6" style="display:none">
```

You get the idea.

Comment: I don't want to have to modify my list of divs, also, I only want to have 1 'More' button

Answer (score 0):

Here you have:

```
   <style>
      /*This hides all items initially*/
      .mydata{
         display: none;
      }
   </style>
```

Now the script

```
   <script>
      var currentPage = 1; //Global var that stores the current page
      var itemsPerPage = 5;
      //This function shows a specific 'page'
      function showPage(page){
          $("#results .mydata").each(function(i, elem){
              if(i >= (page-1)*itemsPerPage && i < page*itemsPerPage) //If item is in page, show it
                $(this).show();
              else
                $(this).hide();
          });
          $("#currentPage").text(currentPage);
      }
      $(document).ready(function(){
          showPage(currentPage);
          $("#next").click(function(){
             showPage(++currentPage);
          });
          $("#prev").click(function(){
             showPage(--currentPage);
          });
      });
   </script>
```

And a sample html:

```
   <div id="results">
      <div class="mydata">data 1</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 2</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 3</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 4</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 5</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 6</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 7</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 8</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 9</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 10</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 11</div>
      <div class="mydata">data 12</div>
   </div>   
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="prev">Previous</a>
   <span id="currentPage"></span>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="next">Next</a>
```

The only thing remaining is to validate fot not going to a page lower than 1 and higher than the total. But that will be easy.

**EDIT**: Here you have it running: http://jsfiddle.net/U8Q4Z/

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! This is also a great implementation that handles 'Previous' and 'Next'. Only problem is if the list is smaller than 6 the navigation links will still be visible.